# What namespace are my classes in when I don't put a namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

if I don't put a namespace in my classes (vs.net 2008), which namespace do my classes get built under?

**update**
Its strange, when I add a namespace I can't seem to reference the classes methods from my user control.

If I explicitly set a namespace, and add a 'using ...' in my control, I still can't see it!

How can this be?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Globals
/// </summary>
public class Globals
{
    public Globals()
    { }


    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }

}
```

My control:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class MyStats : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{




    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    //etc.
```

Comment: Is your class in a separate project from the user control or are they in the same project?

Comment: Also can you post some code - that may help us figure out what is going on.

Comment: Ok I posted some code, I had a namespace in the globals class before but it still didn't work when I referenced it in my control.

Comment: Do you have any compilation errors at all?

Comment: So if you use the type as if intellisense were working it compiles fine? Is it only intellisense that seems to be broken?

Comment: no referencing didn't work, renaming it didn't work.

Comment: Are these two types in separate assemblies?

Comment: It shows up in my class view though, and dragging the property/method on my page it says 'the name globalz does not exist in this context'

Comment: But are they in separate assemblies?

Comment: Please see the edit to my original answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not provide a namespace then your type has no namespace.  Remember that namespaces don't have any meaning post-compile.  They simply get appended to the beginning of you type's name to create a longer name that has a greater probability of being unique.

**Edit:** I think that you may have two separate assemblies and one ought to be referencing the other but it is not.  If two projects are in a single solution then the class viewer will show all types from all projects but that does not necessarily mean that  `ProjectA` references `ProjectB`.  In order to use the types from `ProjectB` in `ProjectA` you need to ensure that a project reference exists.

Comment: "...then your type has no namespace" Not quite, they are placed in the global namespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z2kcy19k.aspx

Answer (score 1):

as you said, that class will not have any namespace, It will be accessible without a using clause.

Namespaces is a feature for putting order on your classes, by classifying, mostly according to their funcionality

**EDIT**

According to your update, i think your "global" class maybe putting trouble because of the  global:: clause... would you mind to change the name of the class just to see if it works?